# WiFi Hotspot - using external DHCP server

Tags: macos, network, wifi, sharing

I've got an iMac set up to share it's wired network connection via WiFi. My MacBook connects to this fine, and is assigned an IP address via DHCP.

However, I'd like to use the MacBook as if it was directly connected to the same network as the iMac. Some addresses on the network do not resolve, and this appears to be because the MacBook is on a different subnet. I'm guessing this is because it's using the iMac as a DHCP server.

Is there a way to have the MacBook share the iMac's network connection, BUT with the MacBook using the same DHCP server as the iMac?

I'd like to avoid manually specifying an IP and subnet.

Comment: It appears it can't be done, at least until Snow Leopard.